# runserver with django crashes until.. it doesnt

Tags: python, django, windows-10

I'm on windows 10 with the latest py (3.6 something) and dango.

I keep getting a crash on first run, and quite often sometimes thereafter, until finally it works. Here's the most recent example. Each of the lines with no output is a crash with a little window informing me of a crash but no information abot what is going wrong:

```
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python -xd .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV>
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
(personDJV) PS C:\Users\roberto\github\python\personDJV> python .\manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 12, 2017 - 12:55:38
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'person.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

From there, it functions perfectly.

With `-v`, this is the output: [gist](https://gist.github.com/robbiemu/623484e8d5de1fc23613af1aaaee1b56)

--
as an update, the problem goes away if I use heroku's local server to run the app :)

Comment: That doesn't show anything unusual... There might be something earlier... You can use [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) to paste all of the output and link here

Comment: @Dawid - updated with full log in gist

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it on different ports like 8001/8080 etc as shown below:

`python .\manage.py runserver 8001`

Comment: I find the same behavor

Answer (score 0):

Or try

```
python -v .\manage.py runserver
```

will run python with more verbose output (lots and lots of lines of output) which should show what's wrong...

Comment: I'd done that, it just wasn't informative to me. I've added the last few lines to the post